# Laravel Migrations: Foreign Key on different connection (different DB)

Tags: database, laravel, migration

#### Possible in Laravel 5

```
Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    ....
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('auth.users')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

This will reference to the `users` table on the `auth` database.

#### Question

How can I make it though that it looks in the `auth` **connection**, rather than directly in the `auth` **database**?

#### Reason

I'm asking because each developer or environment could have a different database name for the same connection. If we used the connection name instead, it would be safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression;


Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $database = DB::connection("auth")->getDatabaseName();
    ....
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on(new Expression($database . '.users'))->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't check it out, but for many similar things in eloquent solution was to simply add DB::raw in a statement.

```
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on(DB::raw('auth.users'))->onDelete('cascade');
```

Didn't test it thought.